# How do I change the permalink of the location where I redirect in Django?

Tags: django

When a user logs in to a Django app, how do I change the URL of the page that shows up after they log in?
I currently have the following view:

```
def users_login(request):
  username = request.POST['username']
  password = request.POST['password']
  user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
  if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/start/")
```

I state that the app should redirect to domain.com/start/, but unfortunately, it does not. It instead goes to domain/login/, which is the location in the action attribute of the login form.

When I have the following code in my view:

```
return redirect('http://www.google.com/')
```

I get an error. I don't understand why. It only happens with forms. After a user submits a form, the URL stays at the action attribute's URL, even though the corresponding view has a redirect to a static page.

Comment: Are you sure that it does not? I believe it first redirects to `"/start/"` and then to `domain/login/`. Check it with Firebug.

Comment: Hello, it does not redirect to /start/ and then to domain/login/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eugene Soldatov is right,

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/start'
```

but you should use [built-in login view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) to make it work (you should use it anyway).

Comment: How would I generalize this to all forms? When a user creates a new post, the URL is still the URL of the form's action attribute, but I want it to be the permalink to the new post.

Comment: @egidra There is no such a problem in Django. Just use `HttpResponseRedirect` or better [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) and everything will be fine.

Comment: I am currently using HttpResponseRedirect, but when a user submits a form, the URL is the value of the form action attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this string to your settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/start/'
```